# Laravel 5.2 controller index returns blank page

Tags: laravel

I created a route to a simple contact page. I use a controller to save the data in the database and display them on the same page. When I submit the form I get a blank page but I want the user to stay on the contact. I tried to pass the index view but then I get errors.

The files are

**route.php**

```
Route::get('contact', 'ContactController@index');

Route::post('contact', 'ContactController@create');
```

**ContactController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Contact;

class ContactController extends Controller
{
   public function index() {
         $contacts = Contact::orderBy('created_at', 'asc')->get();
         return view('/contact', [ 'contacts' => $contacts ]);
}
  public function create(Request $request) {
    $name = $request->input('name');
    $contact = new Contact;
    $contact->name = $name; 
    $contact->save();
    #return view('/contact');
}
}
```

**Contact.php**

```
<?php

Namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Contact extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name'];
}

?>
```

**contact.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Contact page</div>

                <div class="panel-body">
                    {!! Form::open(array('url' => 'contact')) !!}
            {!! Form::label('name', 'Name') !!}
            {!! Form::text('name'); !!}
            {!! Form::submit('Submit'); !!}
            {!! Form::close() !!}
            @if (count($contacts) > 0)
             @foreach ($contacts as $contact) 
            {{ $contact->name }}
                @endforeach
                @endif
        </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Comment: Simply `view('contact'.....)` remove the slash !

Comment: I just was writting the same response as Ismail RBOUH says remeber to acces is with dot instead of slash and without blade.php notation

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: You're getting a blank page because you have commented out the `return` statement. Remove the `#`. And remove the slashes as well.

Comment: instead of returnning view use `return redirect()->back()` after `..->save()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to put `contact.blade.php` inside views folder and use `view('contact', [...])` instead of `view('/contact');`, you don't need the slash and add `return back()` to `create` method:

```
public function create(Request $request) {
    $name = $request->input('name');
    $contact = new Contact;
    $contact->name = $name; 
    $contact->save();
    return back();
}
```

Comment: It does not solve the problem as I already have the view in the correct location and I still get a empty page. After I refresh the browser I return to the index page.